# count how many times a dialog is triggered WATSON Conversations

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation, watson

I need to count how many times a dialog falls into a specific node, and from the third time direct to another node that will request contact information, to talk to it.
It's all done, but I had to make this change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start by initialising a `counter` variable to 0 at your `welcome` node.

In the related node you just set a context variable.

```
"context" { 
  "counter": "<? $counter + 1 ?>"
},
```

Then add a condition to check if `counter` has exceeded a certain value.

```
$counter > 3
```